# Extremum Points of $\frac {2^{2 x + 1} - 3^{2 x + 1} - 6^x \cos(π x)}{4^x + 9^x + 2^{x + 1} 3^x \cos(\pi x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I was looking at the extremum points of the function
$$f(x)=\dfrac {2^{2 x + 1} - 3^{2 x + 1} - 6^x \cos(\pi x)}{4^x + 9^x + 2^{x + 1} 3^x \cos(\pi x)},$$
where $x$ is a real number. I couldn't do it because I couldn't take the derivative of this function (because the derivative of this function is very complicated). Even if I took the derivative, it doesn't end there, you have to find the roots of the derivative function which is even more complicated than the previous step.

Because I didn't do it manually, I used GeoGebra to find the extremum points. The extremum points of this function have an interesting pattern, they are approximately $1.97,2.98,3.98,4.98,\dots,17.98,18,98,\dots$ and so on. But these approximate findings are not satisfactory. I want to know the full answer, and I don't know how to find it.

Comment: Please use `\cos`. Backslashes will generally render things better if they're standard functions...

Comment: In what context where you looking for extrema for this function? If it's a problem from an assignment, what level of maths are you expecting from the solver?

Comment: This is not an assignment or homework. Origin of this problem is my research about recurrence relations. I am expecting that answers maybe be like (for example) first extremum point is $x=ln(23)+1$ , second is $x=ln(46)+2$. complete answers, not approximations. I am looking for the find complete formulation of extremum points (if it is possible of course)

Comment: if this not possible, i accept the answers like (for example), first extremum point is $x=1,78321312312324213123454538538233123555....$ by using computer softwares. as i said before this is not homework this is research. I am trying to understand behaviour of this function, we do not have to find complete solution (NOTE : examples in this comments are arbitrary, not compatible with real solutions)

Comment: Between $-10 \le x \le 10$, we have critical points: $$x==-9.957680458665209||x==-8.961241930302625||x==-7.955773831462836||x==-6.963714343462758||x==-5.951135681259069||x==-4.968741228681721||x==-3.93850022477217||x==-2.97792861759191||x==-1.88913764883188||x==-0.9918825894545658||x==0.9918825894545658||x==1.88913764883188||x==2.97792861759191||x==3.93850022477217||x==4.968741228681721||x==5.951135681259069||x==6.963714343462758||x==7.955773831462836||x==8.961241930302625||x==9.957680458665209$$

Comment: @Dogukan.N: Mathematica is able to find all such things - just tried over the range above and it found critical points, local and global extrema, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Very interesting points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\dfrac {2^{2 x + 1} - 3^{2 x + 1} - 6^x \cos(π x)}{4^x + 9^x + 2^{x + 1} 3^x \cos(π x)}$$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{5\ 6^x \left(2^{x+1} 3^x \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\pi 
   \left(4^x-9^x\right) \sin (\pi  x)+\left(4^x+9^x\right) \log
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \cos (\pi  x)\right)}{\left(4^x+9^x+2^{x+1} 3^x \cos
   (\pi  x)\right)^2}$$

So, we look first for the zeros of function
$$g(x)=2^{x+1} 3^x \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\pi  \left(4^x-9^x\right) \sin (\pi 
   x)+\left(4^x+9^x\right) \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \cos (\pi  x)$$ for which
$$g'(x)=\log (6) \left(2^{x+1} 3^x \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\pi 
   \left(4^x-9^x\right) \sin (\pi  x)\right)+$$ $$\left(\pi ^2
   \left(9^x-4^x\right)+\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \left(4^x \log (4)+9^x
   \log (9)\right)\right) \cos (\pi  x)$$

As you noticed, the solutions are quite close to integer values of $x$. So, use the first iteration of Newton methods with $x_0=n$

and you will have
$$x_1=n-\frac{g(n)}{g'(n)}$$

Now, notice that
$$g(2m)=\left(3^{2m}+2^{2m}\right)^2 \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
$$g(2m+1)=-\left(3^{2 m+1}-2^{2 m+1}\right)^2 \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Simplify $g'(2m)$ and $g'(2m+1)$ in the same manner.

Repeating @Moo's calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
-10 & -9.95477 &  -9.95768 \\
 -9 & -8.95881 &  -8.96124 \\
 -8 & -7.95260 &  -7.95577 \\
 -7 & -6.96159 &  -6.96371 \\
 -6 & -5.94726 &  -5.95114 \\
 -5 & -4.96717 &  -4.96874 \\
 -4 & -3.93239 &  -3.93850 \\
 -3 & -2.97717 &  -2.97793 \\
 -2 & -1.87057 &  -1.88914 \\
 -1 & -0.99178 & -0.99188\\
  1 & 0.99203  &  0.99188 \\
  2 & 1.91158  &  1.88914 \\
  3 & 2.97889  &  2.97793 \\
  4 & 3.94558  &  3.93850 \\
  5 & 4.97063  &  4.96874 \\
  6 & 5.95564  &  5.95114 \\
  7 & 6.96623  &  6.96371 \\
  8 & 7.95948  &  7.95577 \\
  9 & 8.96411  &  8.96124 \\
 10 & 9.96108  &  9.95768
 \end{array}
\right)$$

Now, you just need to classify the points (just compute the second derivative for $x=n$; this should be more than sufficient)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I am grateful to you. I will study and analyze your solution in my time available.